# Did Zordon know about the Samurai Rangers and Nighlocks?

Tags: power-rangers

In Power Rangers Samurai, we know it is the same universe as the original
Power Rangers, Zeo, Turbo, and in Space, because we saw Bulk and Spike, Skull's
son.

Did Zordon know about the Samurai Rangers and their enemies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If power rangers samurai are operating in the same world, they are also operating in a world where zordon has died, before Skull had children. So while he may have known of some of the characters in the power rangers samurai series, Zordon was dead a good 15-20 years prior.

[Zordons death in power rangers in space.](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Countdown_to_Destruction)